# How to print an warning file absent message in Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I'm writing a training application to upload a file to the server.
If a file is not selected, the controller catches the IO Exception, but at the same time I would like to print the warning message in the browser.
It looks like the condition is wrong. How can it be corrected?

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/books/uploadFile}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td th:if="${file.originalFilename}==''">
            <p>File not found</p>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: There is a `</td>` missing, isn't it?

Comment: Do you mean here?
<td th:if="${file.originalFilename}==''">
No, at least in other cases this syntax works properly